# How to have icon in center inside a Checkbox in Android

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, android-linearlayout, center

How can I have an icon in the center of the checkbox. The checkbox has a width and height of `48x48` and the icon is having width and height of `24x24`

Image for reference ( the icon is attached on the left side of checkbox, but I want it to be in center )

[image: Checkbox]

**I have already checked out [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411288/center-checkbox-drawable-within-itself), and they don't seem to work for me. Does anybody has a better approach which I can apply here**

XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_expand_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Items Text" />

    <com.myapp.ui.CheckBoxStates
        android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:cycle_checked_to_indeterminate="false"
        app:cycle_indeterminate_to_checked="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution**

**1-** in your **build.gradle** file implement

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```

**2-** Use **MaterialCheckBox** in your XML file

**by adding**

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:cycle_checked_to_indeterminate="false"
    app:cycle_indeterminate_to_checked="false"/>
```

instead of

```
<com.myapp.ui.CheckBoxStates
    android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:cycle_checked_to_indeterminate="false"
    app:cycle_indeterminate_to_checked="false"/>
```

**OR**

you can inheritance from MaterialCheckBox class to make your own Custom CheckBox View

**Second solution**

Use a new LinearLayout and put your CheckBox inside it
but make LinearLayout with (48dp height and width) and gravity = "center"
and make CheckBox with (wrap_content height and width)

your code should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_expand_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Items Text" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <com.myapp.ui.CheckBoxStates
            android:id="@+id/tags_dialog_tag_item_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:cycle_checked_to_indeterminate="false"
            app:cycle_indeterminate_to_checked="false"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This increases the linear layout width and height to 48x48 but the checkbox remains 24x24 and so is the clickable region because inside `<com.myapp.ui.CheckBoxStates` we are setting layout width to wrap content. And the content which is the image is 24dp.

So the image is 24x24dp and doing wrap content makes the clickable region 24x24dp so doing Linear layout to 48x48 doesn't have any impact as far as I understood. If I am missing something please correct me.

Comment: I added another solution to my answer as the "First Solution", check it now and mark the answer if that is what are you looking for